# Google Universal Analytics - Campaign ID

Tags: google-analytics, marketing

In the Google Universal Analytics doc, they show a parameter called [Campaign ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ci). The problem is that there is no other information about the use and the interest of this parameter. Indeed, all other campaign related parameters are very usual (utm_...) but the Campaign ID seems very odd.

Can anyone provide more insight about it, please?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to correspond with the `utm_id` query parameter.  It is mentioned in the following Google Analytics help documents:

- [Import Campaign Data - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4522476?hl=en)
- [How To Use Master Tracking Codes - Urchin Help](https://support.google.com/urchin/answer/2633697?hl=en)
- [Campaign Tracking - Web Tracking (ga.js) - Google Analytics — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns)

I believe that it is a parameter that was included in Urchin (which Google bought and branded Google Analytics).   It appears that Google no longer recommends the use of this parameter.